# Title and TableofContents in the first page, real contents from second page, how to make it?

Tags: table-of-contents, titles

I want the title and table of contents in the first page, and the real contents start from the second page. But when i use \tableofcontents, all title, TOC, and contents are in the first page. How can I make the contents start from the second page?  And i use article template.

```
...
\title{The title is here}
\author{OUR TEAM}
\date{} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{blablabla...}
...
```

Comment: Put a `\clearpage` after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! concise and exact answer

Comment: @HarishKumar Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I have added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a `\clearpage` after `\tableofcontents`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{This is a dummy article}
\author{A Ghost}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]